# Не показывает изображение с сылки из БД ASP.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

У меня есть некая БД, в которой есть различные сылки на изображения. При работе приложения страница не показывает изображение. Вот код View:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
<div>
    <p><img src="@Model.imageUrl" alt="@Model.imageUrl"></p>
    <p>@Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.hieroglyph) </p>
    <p>Enter hieroglyph: @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.hieroglyph, new { Value = "" })</p>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</div>
}
```

Однако, если я укажу путь вручную, то все работает.

```
<p><img src="~/Content/Images/Hiragana/tsu.jpg"></p>
```

Вот код контролера на всякий:

```
[HttpGet]
    public ActionResult HiraganaTesting()
    {
        HiraganaRapository hiraganarepos = new HiraganaRapository();
        IEnumerable<Hiragana> listWords = hiraganarepos.GetRandom10HiraganaHieroglyphs();
        return View("HiraganaTesting", listWords.ElementAt(0));
    }
```

В Базе у меня лежат обычные строковые сылки, типа: nvarchar, например: *~/Content/Images/Hiragana/tsu.jpg*. Когда учил ASP.NET WebForms, делал что-то подобное и все спокойно работало. Вот начал учить MVC, и столкнулся с такой проблемой.
 Подскажите как мне заставить MVC, показывать изображения)

Comment: покажите кусок кода который генерирует ваше приложение, интересует конкретно то место где должно быть изображение

Answer (score 0, accepted):

у вас ошибка хранения относительных url в базе данных:

```
~/Content/Images/Hiragana/tsu.jpg
```

такой вид понятен серверу, но не понятен клиенту, вам следует избавится от тильды `~`

Comment: Спасибо, теперь понял)

Comment: @Baka, это поможет только в случае когда `Content` в корне сайте

Answer (score 0):

Еще вариант использовать [Url.Content](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.urlhelper.content(v=vs.118).aspx)

```
<p><img src="@Url.Content(Model.imageUrl)" alt="@Model.imageUrl"></p>
```